# custom route with namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

this might be a stupid question but is it possible to add a namespace before the "api" on route?

i have this current code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Api",
    routeTemplate: "{namespace}/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

this "works" but it accepts any words i enter for the {namespace}. i want to add {namespace} on my route because there are controllers with the same name from different namespaces.

Comment: That's a Web API route instead of MVC route (judging from `MapHttpRoute`). Also explain what do you want with `{namespace}` URL parameter.

Comment: so if it is working, what is your question?

Comment: i just want to call a specific Controller from a specific Namespace, for the reason that there are multiple controller with same name but different namespaces in our current project

Comment: @AliZeinali hi as i've mentioned, it is working but i can enter in any words to {namespace} even non existing namespace, but it is calling the controller that i am not referring to

Comment: I think you can use `var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)` & then use `route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { [list of namespace strings you want to accept] }`, or for worst case on duplicate controller names with different namespaces consider implementing custom `IHttpControllerFactory` with `IDependencyResolver` injection.